# Odoo 8 - create automatically open invoice

Tags: odoo-8, invoice, recurring, contract

We're working on Odoo 8, enjoying this app. We'd like to create open invoice automatically for every customer.

We create contracts and it works well, but we still have to click on "generate invoice" and it creates draft invoice.

To those two issues, we didn't find yet any solution on the web.

Would you know a solution ?

Comment: You want to validate invoice at creation ?

Comment: Exactly, make it opened already.
Apparently, contracts create well invoices, at an unknown time during the day concerned. But still it's a draft.
Do you know a way ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the original method to validate invoices after their creation.

```
class AccountAnalyticAccount(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.analytic.account"

    @api.multi
    def _recurring_create_invoice(self, automatic=False):
        invoice_ids = super(AccountAnalyticAccount, self)._recurring_create_invoice(automatic=automatic)
        # Validate invoices here
        self.env['account.invoice'].browse(invoice_ids).signal_workflow('invoice_open')
        return invoice_ids
```

Don't forget module dependance in `__openerp__`:

```
'depends': ['account_analytic_analysis'],
```

Comment: Is this useful ?